# Reading names from a .dat file into a linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, load-data-infile

I've been having some trouble storing and printing data from this file into my linked list.

File Info:

```
Brown Aniya
Canaday Jordan
Germano Thomas
Grant Kiara
Gunathilaka Piyumi
Johnson Demetria
McGill Jayla
Mitchell Ty-Jaa'
Robertson Victoria
Taylor Chloe
Thomas Amon
Watkins Malkym
Wyatt Arkasia
```

Here's the current output:

```
Brown Aniya

--------------------------------
Process exited after 0.1335 seconds with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

The main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "P4-linkedList_Cox.h"

using namespace std; 

int main()
{
    tests oh;

    oh.getNames();
    oh.print();




   return 0;
}
```

the implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "P4-linkedList_Cox.h"

using namespace std;

void tests::getNames()
{
    ifstream inData;
    inData.open("infile.dat");

    nameType *newNode, *nodePtr;

   newNode = new nameType;
   newNode->link= NULL; 
   string um;
        getline(inData, um);
        newNode->info = um;


   if (head != NULL)
   {
      nodePtr = head;

      while (nodePtr->link)
      {
         nodePtr = nodePtr->link;               
      }
     nodePtr->link = newNode;       
   }
   else 
    head = newNode;
}

void tests::print()
{
   nameType *nodePtr;
   nodePtr = head;
   while (nodePtr != NULL)
   {
      cout << nodePtr->info << endl;
      nodePtr = nodePtr->link;
   }


}

tests::tests()
{
    head = NULL;

}
```

and the .h:

```
using namespace std;

class tests
{
    public:
        void getNames();
        void print();
        tests();


    private:
    struct nameType
    {
        string info;
        nameType *link;

    };

    nameType *head;
};
```

Linked lists are still pretty confusing for me, so any help is welcome! I also need more words in this post, I think I explained my problem pretty clearly though. I just need help storing all the names from the .dat file into my linked list and then output that list.

Comment: Your `getNames` is only reading one line, so the linked-list can't contain more than one name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much for the help, however, I manage to get the solution by getting the user to input the number of students then passing that to the function to create a loop. Thanks again for the advice though!

Fixed implementation:

```
void tests::getNames(int students)
{
    ifstream inData;
    inData.open("infile.dat");  

    for(int i = 0; i < students; i++)
    {   
        nameType *newName, *namePtr;
        string um;
        newName= new nameType;
        newName->link= NULL;        
        getline(inData, um);
        newName->info = um;

   if (!head)
      head = newName;
   else  
   {
      namePtr = head;

      while (namePtr->link)
         namePtr = namePtr->link;

      namePtr->link = newName;
   }    

    }

}
```

Output:

```
Enter the number of students: 13
Brown Aniya
Canaday Jordan
Germano Thomas
Grant Kiara
Gunathilaka Piyumi
Johnson Demetria
McGill Jayla
Mitchell Ty-Jaa'
Robertson Victoria
Taylor Chloe
Thomas Amon
Watkins Malkym
Wyatt Arkasia

--------------------------------
Process exited after 3.865 seconds with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you create a single node in your `getNames()` method. For each insertion, you will need to create a new node, fill in that node, and then add it to the linked list, which will need to be in a loop of its own (your current loop just looks for the end of the linked list). Plus, because you initialize the head of the linked list to `NULL`, you never enter your loop to begin with when you perform the test `if(head != NULL)`. This can be accomplished with something like:

```
while(inputFile >> firstName >> lastName) { //reiterate while there is more information to read in
    Person tempPerson(firstName, lastName); //create a new person -- I'm assuming this class exists here with an appropriate constructor
    Node *tempNode = new Node(tempPerson, nullptr); //create a new node on the heap with this person and no next node

    if(head != nullptr) {
        Node* prevNodePtr = nullptr, currNodePtr = head; //start with the head of the list
        while(currNodePtr != nullptr) { //find the end of the list -- currNodePtr will be nullptr when at the end
            prevNodePtr = currNodePtr;
            currNodePtr = currNodePtr->getNextPtr(); //shift both pointers over once
        }
        prevNodePtr->setNext(tempNode); //have the current end of the list point to our new node, making our new node the new end of the list
    }
    else { //head is nullptr, therefore there is not currently a list
        head = tempNode; //change the head to point to this new node
    }
}
```

---

Sidebar: you wanna be sure to close the input file after you're done using it!